# Block regex entry in nginx config

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following entry in a nginx.conf which allows me to use the URL passed in a request.

```
location / {
    if ($args ~ "^uri=(.+)") {
    set $key1 $1;
    proxy_pass $key1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to block/deny certain entries in this so, for example, if the uri argument contains a certain text, let's say example.com, then I want to block it and not allow it to pass or honour the request.

Could anyone help with the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nginx* gives you `$args` (or `$query_string`), containing all the
query string, but will also create variables for each query string
argument. So you can simply run your regex check on `$arg_uri`, to
make it simpler.

To forbid access, the easiest would be to return a 403 HTTP error,
which means "*Forbidden*". Up to you to return a 404 error if you
prefer just saying "*this page doesn't exist*".

```
location / {
    # If the "uri" query parameter contains "example.com" then
    # return a "Forbidden" error.
    if ($arg_uri ~ "example\.com") {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Just be aware that testing "*example.com*" in the `uri` parameter
might not be totally correct, because it would match
`http://www.google.com/?q=example.com`, which probably isn't
what you want. It might then be better to do it like this:

```
location / {
    # If the "uri" query parameter contains "example.com" as
    # domain then return a "Forbidden" error.
    if ($arg_uri ~ "^(https?:)?//([^/]*\.)?example\.com/?") {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

See the regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/6i1AA6/2